# I need to convert hh:mm:ss to seconds

Tags: sqlite

I have a column with elapsed time values in it and they are formated as hh:mm:ss or mm:ss. I had no control over this as the data was imported.

What I need to do is find a way to do a global update to change the values to seconds or find a way to use the sum function on the column in its current format.

One problem is that the data is a mix of mm:ss and hh:mm:ss. The hours field was not zero padded.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR("0000000"||time,LENGTH(time),8),1,2)*3600 + 
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR("0000000"||time,LENGTH(time),8),4,2)*60 + 
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR("0000000"||time,LENGTH(time),8),7,2)
FROM
  table
WHERE
  ...
```

should work with mix of *hh:mm:ss*, *h:mm:ss*, *mm:ss*, *m:ss*, *ss* and *s* formats and also the time separator should be any character.

Comment: YES! That did it. Now I have to decide whether to use this code in an UPDATE statement to fix the database or to just include it in my queries. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Cidtek - I suggest you to add new column `time_sec` to your database and execute simple `update` for each row, so then you can later remove the old `time` column and work faster with `time_sec` information. Good luck!